# Getting SIGEMT error for every code in codechef

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I have been trying some practise questions but codechef ide is giving same error for every code. Even for the codes already submitted for the question.
Here is my code that's coming with the error in codechef ide. Any other submitted code I tried gives me same error !

```cpp
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

    long long int n;
    cin>>n;

    long long int c[n], t[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>c[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>t[i];
    }

    long long int tr = -1, a = -1, b = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(t[i] == 1) {
            if(tr == -1 || tr > c[i]) {
                tr = c[i];
            }
        }
        else if(t[i] == 2) {
            if(a == -1 || a > c[i]) {
                a = c[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            if(b == -1 || b > c[i]) {
                b = c[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if(tr == -1 || a == -1) {
        cout<<b<<endl;
    }
    else if(b == -1 || tr+a < b) {
        cout<<tr+a<<endl;
    }
    else {
        if(tr+a > b) {
            cout<<b<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Related: [why do I get run time error (SIGEMT)](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/why-do-i-get-run-time-error-sigemt/15957)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but be careful with `long long int c[n], t[n];`. If `n` is greater than a couple hundred thousand  the program will probably exhaust the stack. This is but one of many reasons Variable Length Arrays are not included in Standard C++.

Comment: That might be it actually, SIGEMT is Emulator trap, maybe some instruction related to VLAs are unable to be emulated? I cannot see anything else in here that could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of segmentation fault. It may also happen due to accessing memory out of bound, or because the executable file takes up a lot of memory. On submitting the code, the error will be SIGSEGV this also means the same.

Particularly in your code, you have defined two long long int array, they may be taking a lot of memory, try using int, or some other algorithm for the question.